# How to debug golang with dlv in remote container with vscode

Tags: docker, go, debugging, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging

recently I need to do debug for a **single file go binary application** which is contained in the docker under k8s environment with its source code. When I package the docker I use the

> /dlv --listen=:40000 --headless=true --api-version=2 exec /singleExeFile

and expose the 40000 port to the outer VM like

> ports:
> - 40000:40000

When I use my dev environment to connect to outer vm with dlv command. It seems that it can be connected. Like the following

> foo@foo-vm:~$ dlv connect 110.123.123.123:40000
> Type 'help' for list of commands.
> (dlv)

But when use vscode to attach to the code, it meets two error(The vscode has installed go extension)

1. When use legacy connect, there is my launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Connect to server",
            "type": "go",
            "debugAdapter": "legacy",
            "request": "attach",
            "mode": "remote",
            "port": 40000,
            "host": "110.123.123.123",
            "substitutePath": [
                { 
                    "from": "${workspaceFolder}/cmd/maine.go", 
                    "to": "/singleExeFile" 
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But the vscode raises error and I haven't found similar error in google. Error: Socket connection to remote was closed

2. Use the dlv-dap method to connect

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Delve into Docker",
            "type": "go",
            "debugAdapter": "dlv-dap",
            "request": "attach",
            "mode": "remote",
            "port": 40000,
            "host": "110.123.123.123",
            "substitutePath": [
                { 
                    "from": "${workspaceFolder}/cmd/maine.go", 
                    "to": "/singleExeFile" 
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And when try to connect, there is no error raised by vscode. Just try to connect and stop by vscode. Even don't know what's the error.

With verbose param, **there still isn't any output in the DEBUG console** for dlv method. But for legacy method, the following error is outputted. Please check.

By the way, add verbose in legacy method and it raises some detailed message in DEBUG CONSOLE.

```
AttachRequest
Start remote debugging: connecting 110.123.123.123:40000
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"initialized"}
InitializeEvent
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"response","request_seq":2,"command":"attach","success":true}
From client: configurationDone(undefined)
ConfigurationDoneRequest
Socket connection to remote was closed
To client: {"seq":16,"type":"response","request_seq":2,"command":"attach","success":false,"message":"Failed to continue: Check the debug console for details.","body":{"error":{"id":3000,"format":"Failed to continue: Check the debug console for details.","showUser":true}}}
Sending TerminatedEvent as delve is closed
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"terminated"}
From client: disconnect({"restart":false})
DisconnectRequest
```

---

**New Update in 9 July**

I made another try to create a simple docker using the following dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.16.15

RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/www && mkdir -p /var/lib/temp

WORKDIR /var/lib/temp
COPY . ./
RUN go env -w GOPROXY="https://goproxy.cn,direct"
RUN go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest
RUN go mod tidy
RUN go build
RUN mv ./webproj /var/lib/www/ && rm -rf /var/lib/temp

WORKDIR /var/lib/www

COPY ./build.sh ./

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 2345

RUN chmod 777 ./webproj
RUN chmod 777 ./build.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","./build.sh"]
```

And the build.sh code is like

```
dlv --listen=:2345 --headless=true --api-version=2 --accept-multiclient exec ./webproj
```

After that, it works with GoLand debug. GoLand can debug when I send the GET api with designed. But it still can't be work with VSCode. When I use the vscode, it did connect to the docker. But when I add the break point. It shows that this is an unverified BreakPoint and can't stop.

Here is my launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Connect to server",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "attach",
            "mode": "remote",
            "remotePath": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 2345,
            "host": "127.0.0.1"
        }
    ]
}
```

So currently this is blocked. Help is very needed. Thanks.

Comment: "substitutePath" doesn't seem correct. This is used to replace the file path info embedded in the binary. Try `"stopOnEntry": true`, go to "DEBUG CONSOLE", and see what source file path is embedded in the binary using `dlv sources main.go` https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/wiki/debugging#dlv-command-from-debug-console

Comment: Hi hana, it still seems strange. I tried to add the "stopOnEntry": true and remove "substitutePath" attributes. The two settings still do the same behavior as former. For legacy method, the "DEBUG CONSOLE" raises "Socket connection to remote was closed" and stop. For dlv method, there isn't any output in "DEBUG CONSOLE" and stop.

Comment: The legacy mode is no longer supported - but you can see what's going on by enabling the logging `dlv --headless --log --log-output=rpc,dap ...` in the container. For dlv-dap mode, make sure the dlv is the latest version. There is also `substitutePath` example in the debugging doc. Try to enable logging  `"trace": "verbose"` (client-side logging) https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/wiki/debugging#collecting-logs

Comment: Hi Hana, the "trace": "verbose" return the following in the pop up window. 
Expected to connect to external `dlv --headless` server @ v1.7.3 or later via DAP. Older versions fail with "error layer=rpc rpc:invalid character 'C' looking for beginning of value" logged to the terminal.

Comment: Hi Hana, I have updated the DEBUG CONSOLE output in the question body. For the dlv method, no output. But when I try the legacy method, there is some output. Please check.

Comment: Thanks - the output indicates that it couldn't make connection to 110.123.123.123:40000 successfully. You should check the remote dlv --headless process's log.

For dlv-dap, same - enable logging from the remote dlv process side to investigate what's going on.

Comment: Hi Hana, sorry for late update. Recently I have made new try and vscode can connect to the docker dlv already. But I meet the strange thing is that vscode can't add break point. But instead, when I use the GoLand, it does work. So server side should be OK, not quite sure where I made error in settings. I have updated the question body. Please check. Thanks a lot.